# Big issue with chrome, appended dom elements and back behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome, shopping-cart

I'm struggling myself in a apparently solution-less problem.

I'm writing a jQuery cart for a customer (see a demo here: http://thisisnot2.fornacestudio.com/prodotto ).

The cart script is working heavily manipulating dom elements.
The problem is that after posting the order to the form page, if you hit the back button in the browser in Chrome the script stops working (for example: categories don't reveal their content after being clicked).

Does someone know what could cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that hitting the back button is both normal and expected behavior?

Comment: You do know what the error is right?  Just trying to find the solution.

Comment: Matt: are you saying I shouldn't consider the possibility of a user that wants to come back?
Jeff: I don't know what causes the error. Bad loading the js resources would be my first bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you didn't know the error is coming from line 351 in suchi-cart.js

```
jQuery(this).find(".category-content").modal( ... );
```

In the form of `object has no method 'modal'`, I haven't figured out why exactly since I see the script included on the page when hitting the page initially with a hard refresh and when navigating away and going back.

---

**Edit**:
Upon looking into the script more I noticed your using a `lazyload` at the top of the page to including jQuery 1.6.2 via google `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js`

Then in your head tag you also load a local copy of jQuery 1.6.1 via
`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://thisisnot2.fornacestudio.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>`

Finally at the very bottom of the page you include your simplemodal script via 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thisisnot2.fornacestudio.com/wp-content/themes/notatemplate/cart/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.min.js"></script>`

My theory is on a hard refresh of the page the two jQuery scripts are loading first followed by the loading for the simplemodel script which of course extends its `.model()` method and what not onto the jQuery object.

But when you leave the page and go back the scripts loaded via `<script>` jQuery 1.6.1 and simplemodel plugin load instantly but the LazyLoad'd include of jQuery 1.6.2 via Google doesn't run through cache since its a script and thus is loading after the first two scripts overwriting the jQuery object to 1.6.2 and removing the simplemodal script loaded into the object.

So you need to remove lazy loading jQuery from your page.

Comment: Strangely, firebug shows me no error in firefox, but inspecting in Chrome I see it happen on click. And this is here only after coming back.

Comment: thanks for noticing that, the double loading was due to a plugin that I know deactivated.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: The problem is including jQuery in lazyload, when you use the browser back, all scripts included via <script> tags are loaded instantly via cache but LazyLoading javascript causes it to reload, thus all your jQuery plugins are loading before the jQuery library is, so now if you look at the developer toolbar in chrome you'll see these errors `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.  The lazyload and including two jQuery twice was the first problem, the cached script jQuery 1.6.1 tag and simplemodal script were loading instantly via cache but then the Google include was overwriting it

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS! Thanks a lot! It was a bit though to re-organize all of the scripts around the site and give up with LazyLoad, but now it's working like a charme.